# accessing php variable from javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, json

My file is with .php extension.
I have a php variable **$dataSelected** that is an associative array. Actually it's the result set of a select query output. Here is what this variable has when printing with print_r:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [attribute_group_id] => 3
        [language_id] => 1
        [name] => Memory
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [attribute_group_id] => 4
        [language_id] => 1
        [name] => Technical
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [attribute_group_id] => 5
        [language_id] => 1
        [name] => Motherboard
    )

 [3] => Array
    (
        [attribute_group_id] => 6
        [language_id] => 1
        [name] => Processor
    )

)
```

I want to access this variable from within my javascript code snippet(on the same page). My goal is to use the result of the query(which is stored in the **$dataSelected** variable) to dynamically add **option** element to a **select** tag.

I have tried the below code. But it is printing **null** in the console. Can anyone please help what I am doing wrong here?

```
<? php
    $dataSelected = $coreModel -> selectData('*','oc_attribute_group_description');
?>

<script>
 var attrGroups = <?php echo json_encode($dataSelected)?>;
 console.log(attrGroups);
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you can put the php value to a hidden input, and you can import it easily in javascript. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: first try a var_dump($dataSelected) in php. If all is alright, maybe try var attrGroups = '<?php echo json_encode($dataSelected);?>'; or just without the ' but with the extra ;

Comment: put single quotes around php opening and closing tags in javascript. Thanks.

Comment: @MihálovicsRómeó: that's a tricky alternative solution. Thanks. But I would first try to achieve what I explained in the question.

Comment: @Edwin: that did it. Thanks. I could accept yours as the answer if you had posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in: [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899952/accessing-php-variable-from-javascript-code?noredirect=1#comment-72900115)

try:

```
var attrGroups = '<?php echo json_encode($dataSelected);?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
<? php
    $dataSelected = $coreModel -> selectData('*','oc_attribute_group_description');
?>

<script>
 var attrGroups = "<?php echo $dataSelected; ?>";
 console.log(attrGroups);
</script>
```